# Table sorted on key=lambda

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I'm trying to sort a table like below on "val" (ascending order), this is the output :

```
[{'val': '45', 'key': 1}, {'val': '5', 'key': 3}, {'val': '56', 'key': 2}]
```

And this is the input :

```
45 56 5
```

And this is my program :

```
tab = []
i = 0

sequence = input().split()

for seq in sequence:
    i += 1
    tab.append({"key": i, "val": seq})

tri = sorted(tab, key=lambda k: k['val'])

print(tri)
```

So my programs doesn't sort my table on ascending val for this input, any idea ? Thank you !

Comment: I'm going to ask, why do you have `'val': '45', 'key': 1` instead of `1: '45'` as the key and value? To fix it anyway make seq an int `int(seq)`

Comment: what @JohnBarça is saying is that since the value for `k['val'] = seq` then its a string. and string comparisons work in a way where `'46' < '5'` asserts to true

Comment: Thx guys, problem solved :)